# Can I introduce myself as a self taught philosopher?

Tags: logic

I did not ask such for pretentiousness, but for the reason that I may be characterized along with my arguments distinct of other scholars for nobody will know of my endeavor unless I tell them. I would like to do such as well for useful entitlement so as to prove that philosophers are not only those with academic credentials but as well those who is devoted to the love of wisdom even without an academic degree. I do not bother about entitlements but sometimes it is required to support your principle. So I very much require the view of the Philosophy experts to this question.

Comment: It would seem to me most people prefer not to call themselves "philosopher" but rather *teachers* or *students* of philosophy, which probably more accurately describes their actual work...

Comment: It's not illegal.

Comment: -1 This question pertains more to protocol, etiquette or academically, accepted norms hence leading to subjective and argumentative answer. Also, the post is contradictory in the sense that you do not bother "about entitlements" yet require approval of others.

Comment: Philosopher means "one who loves knowledge". So I don't see why one would not call him/herself like that.

Answer (score 7):

Philosophy is a nontrivial endeavor, and honestly, saying you're a "self-taught philosopher" would strike me, and probably most others, as about as reassuring as if you were a "self-taught aerospace engineer".  Yes, it's possible.  But it's much easier to make the claim than to have actually done it.  Your motivations for introducing yourself as such--that you want to prove something--would only reinforce the urge to ask: if you are so interested in philosophy, why did you not bother to get a degree?

So I suspect that while nobody will arrest you, it won't produce the results you are seeking.  If you want to alter the present-day term "philosopher" to mean "anyone devoted to the love of wisdom", well, good luck with that.  If you want people to take you seriously on matters of philosophy, show, don't tell.  If academic philosophers find that you have something interesting to say on some nontrivial topic, that's a much better indication that your self-teaching actually resulted in you being a philosopher rather than someone who merely likes to call themselves one.

Comment: I call myself a philosopher, because I like knowledge. But exactly because I like knowledge, I graduated in biology, not philosophy. After all, I want to understand how nature works, not only what some dead man wrote centuries ago. I read the philosophers, but not only them.

Answer (score 0):

Doing philosophy as distinguished from being a professor of philosophy is, perhaps, the single most divisive issue in academic philosophy today. But to get at this we need, in fact, to enter into prolonged proximity with the texts of the classical cannon and come through to Heidegger who has conduced most impactivly towards this state of affairs. Naturally, what I am naming is the continental analytic divide and the internecine policies there-in resultant. As we all remember from the Sokal affair, many philosophers, at the highest level, are already held to be no more the amateurs....

In a sense this is due to the radicalization of one of the oldest parts of philosophy, the ground of technical terms that arises when everyday insights are inscribed in the body of a discipline. Today such inscriptions are more personalized and more unaccountable in terms of their authentic claims to import then ever. So you too might as well have your word! And it is even demanded of you if you have anything to say.